# Add synonyms for devtools tag

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Web developers starting with Edge or Brave or Opera or any [other](https://www.zdnet.com/pictures/all-the-chromium-based-browsers/) Chromium based browser might not know that their browser is based on Chromium.

Therefore we should add tag synonyms [edge-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge-devtools)[brave-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brave-devtools)[opera-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-devtools) to [google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools). Or [chromium-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromium-devtools) if [this](/q/420569) bears out, then add [chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-devtools), too.